# Why look at power spectral density for stochastic processes?

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, power-spectral-density, stochastic

I have been told that for deterministic signals, it makes sense to look at their respective Fourier transforms/spectra.

For stochastic processes on the other hand, I am supposed to work with power spectral density in terms of qualitative analysis.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a stochastic process itself doesn't *have* a Fourier transform.

That's really all there is to it.

You can only transform signals (i.e. functions over a body isomorphic to $\mathbb R$, for example, functions of time). You can't transform a random variable whose individual realizations are such functions!

Comment: Muller You know you're stuff for sure so I believe you. But my question is then why do I have 20 or so books ( haven't read much of them yet ) on the spectral density in the time-series framework by Priestley, Granger, Brillinger, Parzen, Tukey, Percival and other giants.  Clearly they are dealing with estimation of the spectral density given a stochastic process, so what's up with that ? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand that question

Comment: Hi: Sorry for lack of clarity. What I meant was that I I think ( have to look again at one of the books ), when they discuss estimating the spectral densirty,  they use some kind of version of the fouirier transform where the frequency ( they use $\lambda$ rather than $\pi$ ) is assumed to be a random variable with orthogonal increments. that assumption allows for the handling of the concept that  the process is a stochastic process.

Comment: $\lambda$ instead of $\pi$? That sounds unlikely. Really, maybe hit the books again and then ask clearer, please? But yeah, *spectral estimation* is the estimation of parameters, amongst them frequency, from a stochastic signal. That makes the estimate they get a random variable, too.

Comment: Hi Marcus: I'll try to find something relevant and send a link. thanks.

Comment: Hi Marcus: Section 2.2 of the link below discusses the spectral density of stochastic processes and uses the $\lambda$ notation. In fact, most time series discussions do  Thanks. http://ageconsearch.umn.edu/bitstream/28556/1/wp060001.pdf

Comment: Also, I should have had Marc Nerlove in my previous  "giants" list. My apologies to other giants whom I neglected to mention.

Comment: $\lambda$ is used there as normalized frequency, not instead of $\pi$...

Comment: Marcus: It seems that you know DSP in general very well but maybe particularly this area regarding stochastic processes, spectral density estimation.  If you wouldn't mind, what is the book (I imagine it was a book ) that you like-  recommend for exploring the current topic regarding estimating of spectral density and associated stochastic process theory. I'm curious if I have it. I might and just have not read it. Thanks.

Comment: Steven M. Kay: *Modern Spectral Estimation* for the specest aspects; Oppenheimer for the discrete signal theory; if you're more into *statistical signal processing*, Steven M. Kay's book of the same name.

Comment: thanks. will check out Kay's texts. don't have them.

Answer (score -1):

As @Marcus Müller mentions a stochastic process does not have a Fourier transform.

From a practical point of view, assume you have $N$ realizations of a signal, either deterministic or stochastic. Then, in order to estimate the power spectral density, it is common practice to average the power spectral densities of the individual realizations. For both deterministic and stochastic signals this will result in a more accurate estimate of the power spectral density as $N$ increases.

On the other hand, if you try the same with the Fourier transforms of the individual realizations this will only work for deterministic signals. For stochastic signals the phase of the Fourier transform is random and averaging generally result in a spectrum converging to zero as $N$ increases.

Comment: No, your summation argument for Fourier transforms of the individual realizations doesn't hold in general. Nothing says the phase of your stochastic process is random. This is not the reason!

Comment: Also, no, for deterministic signals averaging will not increase accuracy. How should it? There's nothing inaccurate!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I cannot imagine a stochastic process where, when comparing individual realizations, this is not the case. Any examples?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I should have formulated this more carefully. I think the above still holds when performing actual measurements; i.e. when measuring realizations of an actual deterministic signal in noise. As the measured realizations are finite and (generally) discrete it is then of course no longer correct to talk about the Fourier transform. Applying the DFT to “measured” realizations of a stochastic process typically result in the described behavior (at least I’m not familiar with any counter examples). Admittedly, this is probably not what the OP asked about.

Comment: a noisy signal is a stochastic process, it's pretty much the example I would've used!

Comment: So in that case the amplitude and phase of the signal would be, at least partly, random?

Comment: no, not necessarily in the way you mean "random". For example, receiving the same noisy signal (assuming perfect synchronization) and overlaying would have a perfectly coherently constructing average.