# Power spectral density of surface roughness

Tags: image-processing, frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density, autocorrelation, spectrogram

I am currently working on understanding how visually and intuitively the power spectral density is the fourier transform of the autocorrelation of a signal. I was wondering if anyone had a good explanation that would make sense to someone not directly in the field of signal processing but is now encountering it as a field I have to mesh in for a problem I'm encountering in my field.

Comment: It's simply defined like that; that definition *can* be useful. Your question has been asked on here, before, for example:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we need the power spectral density?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/52402/why-do-we-need-the-power-spectral-density)

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10148/power-spectral-density-vs-energy-spectral-density, https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/47740/why-look-at-power-spectral-density-for-stochastic-processes,  and a lot of things about the Wiener Khinchin Theorem ([e.g.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/59372/power-spectral-density-why-this-2-method-are-equal))